# Publish anonymously

Tags: android, publish, anonymous

I wrote a piece of code that works with internet services of a company that does not allow the usage of other clients than their ones.. But I did it, it faster, better, you have favorites... I mean its a IMPROVEMENT. I contacted them and offered them y solution but they did not agree.. (Its a chatting service, nothing special)

BUT still I would like to publish it.. So my questions are:

- I can forget about Google Play / Android Market, because you are registered with a credit card linked (real name) right? (Will probably publish only on my blog (anonymous blog) and some unofficial markets)
- Creating the APK - are there any steps that I have to watch? I have to sign the application, shall I use a fake name?

I mean I am not doing anything bad, I just want to share my solution but still not get into problems or so...

Comment: yeah, just publish the application in market (play). But be careful of the licenses, using their "api" against their will might cause legal problems to you or to the users of your app

Comment: Hi @ Oliver Goossens you dont want to publish it in android market right ???

Comment: I am interested in practical implementation of "they don't allow the usage of other clients then their ones".. How they did it? Verbally or by law or by user agent kind a..or..?
There are alternative markets for android applications so you could publish it there.. Let us know if that would be good starting position for answer.. Is it possible to give us a bit more details about situation, company, service.. .. ..

Comment: Probably not .... Its their API and if they woudl ocnnect thei API with my name I could get into problems. So probably not .. I mean on google play i stand under my own name and on non markets and on my blog I can be anymous... Just want to figure out what not to forget when doing so.

Comment: Its a company that has a client and its free and they create incombe by ADVERTISEMENT in the app and when I asked them about improvements and about new client, or my client, they refused it because it would shrink they income..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something really interesting:

http://www.howtogeek.com/106175/the-top-5-alternatives-to-the-android-market/